# Marketo Forms2: How to track source

Tags: marketo

I can track the source of a lead doing `go.example.com/?src='ThisSite'` . What I don't know is how to track a form2 that was embedded and I don't find any information. Does anybody know how to do that? thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To accomplish this, you will need to create a hidden field in your form that is auto-populated with the value of the referring page. Here's how to do this in Marketo:

1. Log in to Marketo
2. Under Marketing Activities, select your form and click Edit Form
3. Create a new field
4. Change the field type for the field you created to hidden
5. Select the option for Autofill
6. After the clicking option for Autofill, set Get Value From to Referrer Parameter.
7. Enter the Parameter Name which you want to get from the referrer URL and click SAVE.
8. Click Finish
9. Click Approve and Close